# How to highlight Amchart area using guide, programmatically

Tags: charts, amcharts

I am trying to highlight area on Amcharts but unable to do so with help of guide. I referred an example from [here](http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/vertical-or-horizontal-lines-or-fill-ranges/) below is the code which is not working however if I add a line guide it works.

Here is the JSFiddle code snippet
http://jsfiddle.net/GreyCells/d1ywab37/

```
var guide1 = new AmCharts.Guide();
guide1.category = "2007-01-01";
guide1.toCategory = "2008-01-01";
guide1.lineColor = "#CC0000";
guide1.lineAlpha = 1;
guide1.fillAlpha = 0.2;
guide1.fillColor = "#CC0000";
guide1.dashLength = 2;
guide1.inside = true;
guide1.labelRotation = 90;
guide1.label = "test";
guide1.above = true;
stockPanel1.categoryAxis.addGuide(guide1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems - first, amstock.js is not included, and second, with stock chart, which is date-based you should use guide.date and guide.toDate instead of category and toCategory:

```
guide1.date = new Date(2007, 0, 1);
guide1.toDate = new Date(2008, 0, 1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d1ywab37/1/

Note, months are zero based in JS.